# In SRS reporting, is it possible to assign a statement as an input parameter?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

For example if I declared @SQL as a parameter, could I put an entire script into the text input and have it execute and create a report?

If so, where would I begin?

Comment: You can define a dataset based on a parameter value. So if you input a sql query in the textbox the dataset will be evaluated to that expression and will run it. However as the structure of the dataset will  be known at run time your report could not run if your dataset structure is different to the structure used while building the report.

Comment: If what you mean is to auto create a report layout depending on the @SQL parameter you pass, then the answear is no.